# Accessing the derivatives via the recorder error in example

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to access to the derivatives. Looking at the manual, the recorder should  have it. However, running the below code i receive the error : 
Any idea?

deriv_case = cr.driver_derivative_cases.get_case('rank0:SLSQP|1')

AttributeError: 'SqliteCaseReader' object has no attribute 'driver_derivative_cases'**

```
from openmdao.drivers.scipy_optimizer import ScipyOptimizeDriver

from openmdao.test_suite.components.sellar import SellarDerivativesGrouped
from openmdao.test_suite.components.sellar import SellarProblem

from openmdao.recorders.case_reader import CaseReader
from openmdao.recorders.sqlite_recorder import SqliteRecorder

prob = SellarProblem(SellarDerivativesGrouped)

driver = prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver(optimizer='SLSQP')
driver.recording_options['record_derivatives'] = True
fname = "record.sql"
recorder = SqliteRecorder(fname)
prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)
#driver.add_recorder('recorder')

prob.setup()
prob.run_driver()


prob.cleanup()

cr = CaseReader(fname)

# Get derivatives associated with the first iteration.
deriv_case = cr.driver_derivative_cases.get_case('rank0:SLSQP|1')

# Get all derivatives from that case.
derivs = deriv_case.get_derivatives()

# See what derivatives have been recorded.
print(set(derivs.keys))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example comes from the latest beta docs, which are associated with the current code on the github master branch. I gather you are probably running the most recent release, which is 2.3.1, which doesn't have that feature yet. You could either clone our repo on Github to get the most recent commits to the code, or you could wait until we release 2.4.